# What do the values of the mask parameter returned by findHomography represent?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, homography, ransac

I am using the function `findHomography` of OpenCV with the RANSAC method in order to find the homography that relates two images linked with a set of keypoints.

The main issue is that I haven't been able to find anywhere yet what are the values of the mask matrix that the function outputs.

The only information that I know is that 0 values are outliers, and non zero values are inliers. But what does it mean the inliers value? Does anyone know?

Piece of code where I call `findHomography`:

```
cv::Mat H12;
cv::Mat mask;

H12 = cv::findHomography(FvPointsIm1, FvPointsIm2, mask, CV_RANSAC, 5); 
ui->Debug_Label->setText(Mat2QString(mask));
```

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of the inlier/outlier distinction, or about the numerical values in the mask?

Comment: About the numerical values in the mask.

Comment: Do you ever get values other than `0` or `1`?

Comment: Outliers are 0. Inliers get values, most of them very small. They order of magnitude is between e^-200 and e^-400.

Comment: Could you post the code where you call `findHomography` and then examine the mask values? It would be nice to know the type of your mask input.

Comment: I've just updated it in the top. Thank for the interest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mask returned by `findHomography` is an 8-bit, single-channel `cv::Mat` (or `std::vector<uchar>`, if you prefer) containing either `0` or `1` indicating the outlier status.

**EDIT:** You access each element of the mask by calling `.at<double>`, which is leading to the confusing output. You should be using `.at<uchar>`, which will interpret the matrix value correctly.

Comment: To convert the values of the mask to QString I use the following for each matrix field: ` QString::number(mask.at<double>(i,j)) `

Comment: Nice, that was the mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot print the value correctly by using: `mask.at<uchar>(0, 0)`. It prints a small matrix icon with values "0 0, 0 1"... Do you know why?

Comment: Okay... It is just that I call findHomography() exactly as he does, and when I print `cout << mask.at<uchar>(0, 0) << endl;` as you proposed, I don't get a 0 or a 1. I will see to ask another question if you think it is different as here.

Comment: @user1368342 I've reproduced your problem. Cast the result to an `int` to see the numerical value, like so: `cout << (int)mask.at<uchar>(0,0) << endl;`

Comment: @Aurelius, you are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456788/opencv-how-to-get-inlier-points-using-findhomography-findfundamental-and-ra/24456789#24456789 Here is the question and also the answer. It was quite trivial after all. :P

Answer (score 2):

I used the *findHomography* method after applying keypoint matching.

- **Inliers**
  are matched keypoints that are calculated to be true positives (correct matches);
- **Outliers**
  are matched keypoints that are calculated to be false positives (false matches).

Then you can use the mask output to extract the subset of correct matches from all matches.

- There is an example in Python 3.6 & OpenCV 3.4.1:

  ```
  good_kp = [gray_kp[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good_matches]
  correct_matched_kp = [good_kp[i] for i in range(len(good_kp)) if mask[i]]
  ```